# I have Haslell Directions and how to make it Ints?

Tags: haskell

I have Directions and I step 1 like that

THis is the directions:

```
 North (x,y) = (x,y+1)
 East (x,y) = (x+1,y)
South (x,y) = (x, y-1)
 West (x,y) = (x-1, y)
```

How to implement like that?

```
   f13 :: [Dir] -> (Int,Int)
    f13 [North, North]                == (0,2)
    f13 [North, East, South, West]    == (0,0)
    f13 (replicate 10 East)           == (10,0)
```

My code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
f13 :: [Dir] -> (Int,Int)
--f13 xs  = (a,b+1)
f13 xs | xs == North = (a,b+1)
       | xs == East = (a+1,b)
       | xs == South = (a,b-1)
       | xs == West = (a-1,b)
       | otherwise = (a,b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I understand that you have a **data type** named `Dir` which has **constructors** of `North`, `South`, `East`, and `West`:

```
data Dir = North | South | East | West
```

And that you want to create a function that computes a new location on a grid using a beginning location and a list of steps in terms of many **values** of **type** `Dir`, which is where we get the list `[Dir]`.

If that is correct then consider making two separate functions.  The first function will take one step at a time.  We can simply match each pattern (North, South, East, West) and handle each case separately:

```
step :: (Int, Int)    -- ^ The starting point
     -> Dir           -- ^ The direction to step
     -> (Int, Int)    -- ^ Where we end up
step (x,y) North = (x,y+1)
step (x,y) South = (x,y-1)
step (x,y) East  = (x+1,y)
step (x,y) West  = (x-1,y)
```

Now that we have the basic mapping, which defines how `Dir` relates to our grid, we can repeatedly apply that to a list of directions.   I'll leave this part up to you.  You can look around for how to use a fold - particularly `foldl` - to solve the problem or you can make your own primitive recursive function.